# Fragment + swipe + drawermenu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I realized my "swipe " project between two fragments that works. I also have my project with my walking drawer menu. I try to link the two but following this assembly code , which contains my MainActivity my menu must become / be as a fragment. So many functions change language / writing .

[there a easy idea of my plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLSBE.png)

Here is my code MainActivity :

```
    package thyroid.com.thyroidmenu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;


import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;


public class MainActivity extends Fragment {
public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
public Toolbar toolbar;


/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
public GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    initNavigationDrawer();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

}

public void initNavigationDrawer() {

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    assert navigationView != null;
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


            int id = menuItem.getItemId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.home:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.connection:

                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainlogin);

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);


                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.settings:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.trash:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trash", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.logout:
                    finish();


            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView tv_email = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
    tv_email.setText("thyroid.mobileapp@gmail.com");
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View v) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(v);
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://thyroid.com.thyroidmenu/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://thyroid.com.thyroidmenu/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}


     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View MainActivity = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        ((TextView)MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("iOS");
        return MainActivity;
    }}
```

And here are the errors that are just bad writing :

[MY ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnrJQ.jpg)

How do I change my setContentView / getApplicationContext / findViewById ... etc to fit in a fragment ?

Do I have to make my process with fragments to realize this little montage (see picture 1) ? The fragments will seem practical and me in any case very useful later ...

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by getActivity().function_name() i.e. functions you have mentioned in your question , in your fragment. But that is not the right way. You can follow up the instructions given here for a drawer layout.

http://slidenerd.com/2015/07/22/android-design-support-library/

Answer (score 0):

There what I obtained after the modifications :

```
package thyroid.com.thyroidmenu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;


import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public Toolbar toolbar;


/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
public GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    initNavigationDrawer();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

}

public void initNavigationDrawer() {

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    assert navigationView != null;
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


            int id = menuItem.getItemId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.home:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.connection:

                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainlogin);

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);


                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.settings:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.trash:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trash", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.logout:



            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView tv_email = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
    tv_email.setText("thyroid.mobileapp@gmail.com");
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View v) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(v);
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://thyroid.com.thyroidmenu/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://thyroid.com.thyroidmenu/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}
}
```

The code which realise the swipe :

```
package thyroid.com.thyroidmenu;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

 public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            //Fragment for Android Tab
            return new Windows();
        case 1:
            //Fragment for Ios Tab
            return new MainActivity();
              }
    return null;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3; //No of Tabs
}


 }
```

And the errors are :

[there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgnxC.jpg)

As I dont use "fragment" for my toolbarmenu/drawermenu it can't works.
I should maybe try to separate the menu is an other class and then call it in the fragment. but how ?... ;)

Answer (score -1):

Your **MainActivty** is extending **Fragment** replace **Fragment** by **AppCompactActivity**. And delete your **onCreateView** method placed at bottom of your class there is no need of that method. If you need below line of code:

`((TextView)MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("iOS");`

mentioned in your **onCreateView** method then you can move this line of code to **onCreate** method. But you have to it write as follows in **onCreate** method:

`((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("iOS");`

Nothing else line of code is required from **onCreateView** method so delete that method.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. With "AppCompactActivity", i've have still this error:"Error:(21, 24) error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to Fragment". So I tried with "FragmentActivity" but I obtained this :"Error:(21, 24) error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to Fragment"... Any Idea ?

Comment: @zouarv42 on replacing `public class MainActivity extends Fragment` with   `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity` can you post the image of error log that you get. Also the latest code after modification.

Comment: @zouarv42 please accept the answer since it is working.